# XSLT - moving nth first child as first and placing the rest of its childrens

Tags: xslt

Iam trying to transform a reference xml to other dtd specific

Input:

```
<ref>
   <a>text</a>
   <b>text</b>
   <c>text</c>
   <d>text</d>
</ref>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="ref">
    <ref>
        <h>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./a"/>
        </h>
        <g>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </g>
    </ref>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ref/a">
    <a>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Output derived:

```
<ref>
  <h>
     <a>text</a>
  </h>
  <g>
     <a>text</a>
     <b>text</b>
     <c>text</c>
     <d>text</d>
  </g>
</ref>
```

Desired output:

```
<ref>
  <h>
     <a>text</a>
  </h>
  <g>
     <b>text</b>
     <c>text</c>
     <d>text</d>
  </g>
</ref>
```

Should i be using mode to do this or should be calling template for, if so how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used 'mode' to get it done.

```
<xsl:template match="ref">
   <ref>
      <h>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./a" mode="add"/>
      </h>
      <g>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </g>
   </ref>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ref/a"/>
<xsl:template match="ref/a" mode="add">
    <a>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is more what you want to do:

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ref">
    <ref>
      <h>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[1]"/>
      </h>
      <g>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[generate-id() != generate-id(../*[1])]"/>
      </g>
    </ref>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ref/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: what if im not doing it with my first child and want to do it with nth child or multiple childs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    <g>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </g>
```

use

```
    <g>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except a"/>
    </g>
```

in XSLT 2.0